# onblur event prevent onclick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

Trying to choose the item in the dropdown list.
When I am trying to click on the item, it is not clicking because of onBlur.
I see many solutions with a onMouseDown, but many people say this is not a good solution. Also do not like idea with the timeout, not a good practice.

Please help to have a solution for this case using onClick

```
const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

const onBlur = (e)=>{
    setShow(false)
  }

<div className="dropdown"  onFocus={onFocus}>
      <input
        aria-expanded={show ? true : false}
        type="text"
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setValue(e.target.value)
          geoDataArr.length === 0 ? setShow(false) : setShow(true)
        }}
        onBlur={onBlur}
      />
      <div className={`dropdown-menu ${show ? "show" : ""}`}>
        {geoDataArr.map((item, i) =>(
          <li
            className="dropdown-item"
            key={i}
            onClick={e=>{
              setValue(e.target.dataset.city)
              // setShow(false)
            }}
            style={{cursor:"pointer"}}
            data-city={item.name}
          >
            <img src={`https://flagcdn.com/w40/${item.country.toLowerCase()}.png`} alt={item.country} />
            &nbsp;
            {item.name}
            &nbsp;
            {item.state}
          </li>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
```